# Looking for a list of all available languages in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

I don't seem to be able to find a comprehensive list of all language options available in any given iOS version. I am considering my options for app localization and would like to be able to compare available language options in different iOS releases.

Could someone please tell me how I could create such a list programatically?

I think this way I could generate the list for any available iOS version and compare the results.

Comment: Starting in Xcode 12.5, all ISO 639 languages are available for localization!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no definite published list (as far as I know), for the simple reason that the locales list might change even in minor version updates.

The closes you get to such list is the Language Support section of the iPhone technical specs:
 - [iPhone 4](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html)
 - [iPhone 3GS](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP495)
 - [iPhone 3G](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP495)
 - [iPhone 2](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP2) is actually missing this section

If you want the definitive list of languages and locales supported by specific *iOS version*, you should write a simple program that uses [`NSLocale::availableLocaleIdentifiers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001224) to obtain the list, and [`NSLocale::componentsFromLocaleIdentifier:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001224) to extract the canonical codes (or the corresponding `CFLocale`).

Comment: **Swift 4** example:

`static func languages() -> [String] {
        var languages = [String]()
        let currentLocale = NSLocale.current as NSLocale

        for languageCode in NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers {
            if let name = currentLocale.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.languageCode, value: languageCode), !languages.contains(name) {
                languages.append(name)
            }
        }
        return languages.sorted()
    }`

Answer (score 25):

This is the list of **avaliableLocalIdentifiers** with the english locale description,

taken from *iPod* touch *iOS 6.0.1*.

I do not believe that all these are supported for localisation!

```
en_IE - English (Ireland)

ro_MD - Romanian (Moldova)

br - Breton

en_GY - English (Guyana)

es_GT - Spanish (Guatemala)

shi_Tfng_MA - Tachelhit (Tifinagh, Morocco)

mr - Marathi

bs - Bosnian

en_AS - English (American Samoa)

ksf - Bafia

sr_Latn_ME - Serbian (Latin, Montenegro)

ms - Malay

ms_MY - Malay (Malaysia)

mt - Maltese

ha - Hausa

nb_NO - Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)

en_BZ - English (Belize)

pt_BR - Portuguese (Brazil)

or_IN - Oriya (India)

is_IS - Icelandic (Iceland)

mn_Cyrl_MN - Mongolian (Cyrillic, Mongolia)

ar_IQ - Arabic (Iraq)

he - Hebrew

zh_Hans_CN - Chinese (Simplified, China)

my - Burmese

bas - Basaa

mer - Meru

en_JM - English (Jamaica)

dz_BT - Dzongkha (Bhutan)

teo_KE - Teso (Kenya)

cy_GB - Welsh (United Kingdom)

sg - Sango

it_CH - Italian (Switzerland)

de_LU - German (Luxembourg)

en_US - English (United States)

hi - Hindi

hu_HU - Hungarian (Hungary)

uz_Latn_UZ - Uzbek (Latin, Uzbekistan)

af_NA - Afrikaans (Namibia)

si - Sinhala

fr_BI - French (Burundi)

ga_IE - Irish (Ireland)

mfe - Morisyen

en_CA - English (Canada)

ne_IN - Nepali (India)

rwk_TZ - Rwa (Tanzania)

en_AU - English (Australia)

sk - Slovak

teo - Teso

sl - Slovenian

tk_Latn_TM - Turkmen (Latin, Turkmenistan)

tzm_Latn - Central Morocco Tamazight (Latin)

ee_GH - Ewe (Ghana)

kde - Makonde

sn - Shona

dyo_SN - Jola-Fonyi (Senegal)

mas_TZ - Masai (Tanzania)

en_SG - English (Singapore)

so - Somali

nyn_UG - Nyankole (Uganda)

br_FR - Breton (France)

fr_BJ - French (Benin)

pt_MZ - Portuguese (Mozambique)

hr - Croatian

az_Latn - Azerbaijani (Latin)

sq - Albanian

sr - Serbian

sw_KE - Swahili (Kenya)

ca - Catalan

hu - Hungarian

et_EE - Estonian (Estonia)

lag_TZ - Langi (Tanzania)

nb - Norwegian Bokmål

bn_IN - Bengali (India)

sv - Swedish

th_TH - Thai (Thailand)

ml_IN - Malayalam (India)

sr_Cyrl_RS - Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)

sw - Swahili

nd - North Ndebele

ta_IN - Tamil (India)

fr_MQ - French (Martinique)

hy - Armenian

ne - Nepali

es_AR - Spanish (Argentina)

pt_AO - Portuguese (Angola)

ne_NP - Nepali (Nepal)

ar_BH - Arabic (Bahrain)

hi_IN - Hindi (India)

bo_IN - Tibetan (India)

seh - Sena

de_DE - German (Germany)

fr_BL - French (Saint Barthélemy)

fr_MR - French (Mauritania)

fa_IR - Persian (Iran)

nl - Dutch

es_PR - Spanish (Puerto Rico)

en_PW - English (Palau)

rn_BI - Rundi (Burundi)

nn - Norwegian Nynorsk

kk_Cyrl - Kazakh (Cyrillic)

sl_SI - Slovenian (Slovenia)

dua - Duala

kea - Kabuverdianu

ig_NG - Igbo (Nigeria)

kln - Kalenjin

yo - Yoruba

sv_FI - Swedish (Finland)

ru_MD - Russian (Moldova)

en_ZW - English (Zimbabwe)

brx_IN - Bodo (India)

fil_PH - Filipino (Philippines)

cs - Czech

pt_GW - Portuguese (Guinea-Bissau)

bn_BD - Bengali (Bangladesh)

de_AT - German (Austria)

luo - Luo

sk_SK - Slovak (Slovakia)

ar_001 - Arabic (World)

es_US - Spanish (United States)

ta - Tamil

mk_MK - Macedonian (Macedonia)

om_KE - Oromo (Kenya)

da_DK - Danish (Denmark)

ko_KR - Korean (South Korea)

shi_Latn - Tachelhit (Latin)

ff_SN - Fulah (Senegal)

id - Indonesian

sr_Cyrl_ME - Serbian (Cyrillic, Montenegro)

kde_TZ - Makonde (Tanzania)

cy - Welsh

mgh - Makhuwa-Meetto

te - Telugu

fr_GN - French (Guinea)

fo_FO - Faroese (Faroe Islands)

ig - Igbo

it_IT - Italian (Italy)

uk_UA - Ukrainian (Ukraine)

tg - Tajik

vai - Vai

bm_ML - Bambara (Mali)

en_SL - English (Sierra Leone)

ii - Sichuan Yi

ses - Koyraboro Senni

th - Thai

ti - Tigrinya

ru_KZ - Russian (Kazakhstan)

te_IN - Telugu (India)

tk - Turkmen

cs_CZ - Czech (Czech Republic)

ar_AE - Arabic (United Arab Emirates)

brx - Bodo

haw - Hawaiian

tzm_Latn_MA - Central Morocco Tamazight (Latin, Morocco)

so_DJ - Somali (Djibouti)

uz_Cyrl_UZ - Uzbek (Cyrillic, Uzbekistan)

to - Tongan

ewo_CM - Ewondo (Cameroon)

nl_AW - Dutch (Aruba)

ar_MR - Arabic (Mauritania)

sn_ZW - Shona (Zimbabwe)

en_IN - English (India)

en_TT - English (Trinidad and Tobago)

tr - Turkish

is - Icelandic

fr_GP - French (Guadeloupe)

luy - Luyia

es_NI - Spanish (Nicaragua)

it - Italian

da - Danish

kln_KE - Kalenjin (Kenya)

tk_Latn - Turkmen (Latin)

en_BB - English (Barbados)

ar_DZ - Arabic (Algeria)

ar_SY - Arabic (Syria)

ha_Latn - Hausa (Latin)

en_MH - English (Marshall Islands)

mr_IN - Marathi (India)

en_GB - English (United Kingdom)

de - German

fr_GQ - French (Equatorial Guinea)

ky_KG - Kirghiz (Kyrgyzstan)

pt_PT - Portuguese (Portugal)

fr_RW - French (Rwanda)

nus_SD - Nuer (Sudan)

asa - Asu

zh - Chinese

ha_Latn_GH - Hausa (Latin, Ghana)

bo_CN - Tibetan (China)

kam_KE - Kamba (Kenya)

dua_CM - Duala (Cameroon)

khq_ML - Koyra Chiini (Mali)

ur_IN - Urdu (India)

ro_RO - Romanian (Romania)

om - Oromo

ksb_TZ - Shambala (Tanzania)

gu_IN - Gujarati (India)

fr_TD - French (Chad)

jmc - Machame

ja_JP - Japanese (Japan)

so_ET - Somali (Ethiopia)

nl_NL - Dutch (Netherlands)

es_ES - Spanish (Spain)

or - Oriya

yo_NG - Yoruba (Nigeria)

es_PY - Spanish (Paraguay)

mua_CM - Mundang (Cameroon)

fa_AF - Persian (Afghanistan)

en_HK - English (Hong Kong SAR China)

luo_KE - Luo (Kenya)

ja - Japanese

twq - Tasawaq

en_BE - English (Belgium)

es_UY - Spanish (Uruguay)

dje_NE - Zarma (Niger)

luy_KE - Luyia (Kenya)

naq - Nama

si_LK - Sinhala (Sri Lanka)

zu - Zulu

bs_BA - Bosnian (Bosnia and Herzegovina)

zh_Hans_MO - Chinese (Simplified, Macau SAR China)

fr_KM - French (Comoros)

zh_Hant_HK - Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong SAR China)

dz - Dzongkha

swc - Congo Swahili

asa_TZ - Asu (Tanzania)

az_Cyrl - Azerbaijani (Cyrillic)

ewo - Ewondo

gv_GB - Manx (United Kingdom)

ti_ER - Tigrinya (Eritrea)

be_BY - Belarusian (Belarus)

uk - Ukrainian

nyn - Nyankole

cgg_UG - Chiga (Uganda)

de_CH - German (Switzerland)

fr_TG - French (Togo)

jmc_TZ - Machame (Tanzania)

ta_LK - Tamil (Sri Lanka)

so_SO - Somali (Somalia)

es_DO - Spanish (Dominican Republic)

fr_LU - French (Luxembourg)

shi_Latn_MA - Tachelhit (Latin, Morocco)

swc_CD - Congo Swahili (Congo - Kinshasa)

kn_IN - Kannada (India)

hy_AM - Armenian (Armenia)

fil - Filipino

bas_CM - Basaa (Cameroon)

ar_TD - Arabic (Chad)

ur - Urdu

bez_TZ - Bena (Tanzania)

haw_US - Hawaiian (United States)

tg_Cyrl - Tajik (Cyrillic)

pa - Punjabi

ee_TG - Ewe (Togo)

ti_ET - Tigrinya (Ethiopia)

sr_Latn_BA - Serbian (Latin, Bosnia and Herzegovina)

ee - Ewe

sv_SE - Swedish (Sweden)

ki_KE - Kikuyu (Kenya)

zh_Hans - Chinese (Simplified)

bem - Bemba

uz - Uzbek

ar_YE - Arabic (Yemen)

seh_MZ - Sena (Mozambique)

ru_UA - Russian (Ukraine)

fr_SC - French (Seychelles)

ar_KM - Arabic (Comoros)

en_ZA - English (South Africa)

nn_NO - Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway)

mas_KE - Masai (Kenya)

ar_EG - Arabic (Egypt)

el - Greek

pl - Polish

nl_BE - Dutch (Belgium)

en - English

uz_Latn - Uzbek (Latin)

eo - Esperanto

shi - Tachelhit

kok - Konkani

mas - Masai

fr_FR - French (France)

rof - Rombo

en_MP - English (Northern Mariana Islands)

de_BE - German (Belgium)

ar_EH - Arabic (Western Sahara)

es_CL - Spanish (Chile)

en_VI - English (U.S. Virgin Islands)

es - Spanish

ps - Pashto

et - Estonian

vai_Latn - Vai (Latin)

pt - Portuguese

eu - Basque

ka - Georgian

fr_NE - French (Niger)

eu_ES - Basque (Spain)

mgh_MZ - Makhuwa-Meetto (Mozambique)

zu_ZA - Zulu (South Africa)

ar_SA - Arabic (Saudi Arabia)

chr_US - Cherokee (United States)

cgg - Chiga

lag - Langi

az_Latn_AZ - Azerbaijani (Latin, Azerbaijan)

es_VE - Spanish (Venezuela)

el_GR - Greek (Greece)

el_CY - Greek (Cyprus)

mfe_MU - Morisyen (Mauritius)

ki - Kikuyu

vi - Vietnamese

rwk - Rwa

bez - Bena

kk - Kazakh

kl - Kalaallisut

zh_Hant - Chinese (Traditional)

fr_CA - French (Canada)

km - Khmer

es_HN - Spanish (Honduras)

agq_CM - Aghem (Cameroon)

kn - Kannada

ii_CN - Sichuan Yi (China)

mn_Cyrl - Mongolian (Cyrillic)

en_BM - English (Bermuda)

ko - Korean

ln_CD - Lingala (Congo - Kinshasa)

en_GM - English (Gambia)

es_CO - Spanish (Colombia)

guz_KE - Gusii (Kenya)

es_PA - Spanish (Panama)

twq_NE - Tasawaq (Niger)

en_NZ - English (New Zealand)

fa - Persian

en_US_POSIX - English (United States, Computer)

dav_KE - Taita (Kenya)

lt_LT - Lithuanian (Lithuania)

en_SZ - English (Swaziland)

ar_SD - Arabic (Sudan)

rof_TZ - Rombo (Tanzania)

uz_Arab_AF - Uzbek (Arabic, Afghanistan)

vi_VN - Vietnamese (Vietnam)

en_MT - English (Malta)

kw - Cornish

yav_CM - Yangben (Cameroon)

ta_MY - Tamil (Malaysia)

ru_KG - Russian (Kyrgyzstan)

kab - Kabyle

ky - Kirghiz

ff - Fulah

en_PG - English (Papua New Guinea)

to_TO - Tongan (Tonga)

ar_LY - Arabic (Libya)

af_ZA - Afrikaans (South Africa)

de_LI - German (Liechtenstein)

sr_Cyrl_BA - Serbian (Cyrillic, Bosnia and Herzegovina)

fi - Finnish

ksf_CM - Bafia (Cameroon)

khq - Koyra Chiini

gsw - Swiss German

es_SV - Spanish (El Salvador)

fr_DJ - French (Djibouti)

en_MU - English (Mauritius)

sr_Latn - Serbian (Latin)

pl_PL - Polish (Poland)

kea_CV - Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde)

pa_Arab - Punjabi (Arabic)

fr_MC - French (Monaco)

en_PH - English (Philippines)

saq - Samburu

ar_PS - Arabic (Palestinian Territories)

fr_CD - French (Congo - Kinshasa)

bem_ZM - Bemba (Zambia)

ru_RU - Russian (Russia)

uz_Cyrl - Uzbek (Cyrillic)

pa_Guru - Punjabi (Gurmukhi)

vai_Vaii - Vai (Vai)

fo - Faroese

so_KE - Somali (Kenya)

ln_CG - Lingala (Congo - Brazzaville)

ar_OM - Arabic (Oman)

pt_ST - Portuguese (São Tomé and Príncipe)

kl_GL - Kalaallisut (Greenland)

fr - French

es_CR - Spanish (Costa Rica)

ses_ML - Koyraboro Senni (Mali)

tzm - Central Morocco Tamazight

mer_KE - Meru (Kenya)

xog - Soga

xog_UG - Soga (Uganda)

nl_SX - Dutch (Sint Maarten)

en_FJ - English (Fiji)

en_MW - English (Malawi)

ar_MA - Arabic (Morocco)

kam - Kamba

am_ET - Amharic (Ethiopia)

af - Afrikaans

ar_TN - Arabic (Tunisia)

es_PE - Spanish (Peru)

sbp_TZ - Sangu (Tanzania)

fr_CF - French (Central African Republic)

vun_TZ - Vunjo (Tanzania)

lg - Ganda

ar_JO - Arabic (Jordan)

ebu - Embu

fr_RE - French (Réunion)

ha_Latn_NG - Hausa (Latin, Nigeria)

lv_LV - Latvian (Latvia)

ak - Akan

chr - Cherokee

az_Cyrl_AZ - Azerbaijani (Cyrillic, Azerbaijan)

dav - Taita

es_419 - Spanish (Latin America)

ebu_KE - Embu (Kenya)

fr_MF - French (Saint Martin)

am - Amharic

en_PK - English (Pakistan)

fr_CG - French (Congo - Brazzaville)

dje - Zarma

dyo - Jola-Fonyi

pa_Guru_IN - Punjabi (Gurmukhi, India)

ln - Lingala

ak_GH - Akan (Ghana)

ar_DJ - Arabic (Djibouti)

en_BS - English (Bahamas)

lo - Lao

zh_Hant_TW - Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)

lg_UG - Ganda (Uganda)

ar_KW - Arabic (Kuwait)

ar - Arabic

fr_MG - French (Madagascar)

ca_ES - Catalan (Spain)

as - Assamese

he_IL - Hebrew (Israel)

sbp - Sangu

fr_GA - French (Gabon)

mg_MG - Malagasy (Madagascar)

my_MM - Burmese (Myanmar [Burma])

ps_AF - Pashto (Afghanistan)

fr_CH - French (Switzerland)

vun - Vunjo

lt - Lithuanian

kk_Cyrl_KZ - Kazakh (Cyrillic, Kazakhstan)

ga - Irish

en_FM - English (Micronesia)

lu - Luba-Katanga

nmg - Kwasio

es_BO - Spanish (Bolivia)

lv - Latvian

fr_YT - French (Mayotte)

km_KH - Khmer (Cambodia)

teo_UG - Teso (Uganda)

fr_SN - French (Senegal)

om_ET - Oromo (Ethiopia)

ms_BN - Malay (Brunei)

ar_ER - Arabic (Eritrea)

gsw_CH - Swiss German (Switzerland)

az - Azerbaijani

fi_FI - Finnish (Finland)

tr_TR - Turkish (Turkey)

fr_CI - French (Côte d’Ivoire)

en_UM - English (U.S. Minor Outlying Islands)

sr_Cyrl - Serbian (Cyrillic)

ur_PK - Urdu (Pakistan)

hr_HR - Croatian (Croatia)

nl_CW - Dutch (Curaçao)

nmg_CM - Kwasio (Cameroon)

en_GU - English (Guam)

es_EC - Spanish (Ecuador)

gl_ES - Galician (Spain)

zh_Hant_MO - Chinese (Traditional, Macau SAR China)

gl - Galician

mt_MT - Maltese (Malta)

ha_Latn_NE - Hausa (Latin, Niger)

en_NA - English (Namibia)

rm - Romansh

kw_GB - Cornish (United Kingdom)

zh_Hans_SG - Chinese (Simplified, Singapore)

rn - Rundi

ro - Romanian

rm_CH - Romansh (Switzerland)

saq_KE - Samburu (Kenya)

vai_Vaii_LR - Vai (Vai, Liberia)

ka_GE - Georgian (Georgia)

es_GQ - Spanish (Equatorial Guinea)

sr_Latn_RS - Serbian (Latin, Serbia)

zh_Hans_HK - Chinese (Simplified, Hong Kong SAR China)

agq - Aghem

gu - Gujarati

lo_LA - Lao (Laos)

ru - Russian

en_SB - English (Solomon Islands)

gv - Manx

en_BW - English (Botswana)

yav - Yangben

ta_SG - Tamil (Singapore)

fr_BE - French (Belgium)

bg_BG - Bulgarian (Bulgaria)

es_MX - Spanish (Mexico)

rw - Kinyarwanda

be - Belarusian

nd_ZW - North Ndebele (Zimbabwe)

mua - Mundang

kab_DZ - Kabyle (Algeria)

bg - Bulgarian

tg_Cyrl_TJ - Tajik (Cyrillic, Tajikistan)

mg - Malagasy

sg_CF - Sango (Central African Republic)

pa_Arab_PK - Punjabi (Arabic, Pakistan)

sw_TZ - Swahili (Tanzania)

en_SC - English (Seychelles)

nus - Nuer

shi_Tfng - Tachelhit (Tifinagh)

ar_QA - Arabic (Qatar)

naq_NA - Nama (Namibia)

fr_BF - French (Burkina Faso)

rw_RW - Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)

as_IN - Assamese (India)

guz - Gusii

ksb - Shambala

fr_ML - French (Mali)

mk - Macedonian

kok_IN - Konkani (India)

sq_AL - Albanian (Albania)

ml - Malayalam

fr_GF - French (French Guiana)

bm - Bambara

lu_CD - Luba-Katanga (Congo - Kinshasa)

fr_CM - French (Cameroon)

bn - Bengali

ar_LB - Arabic (Lebanon)

id_ID - Indonesian (Indonesia)

uz_Arab - Uzbek (Arabic)

mn - Mongolian

bo - Tibetan

vai_Latn_LR - Vai (Latin, Liberia)
```

Comment: Is there any API for this list

Comment: Here's the code to access API, works on iOS 14.4 simulator:                                                                                
        let availableLocaleIDs = Locale.availableIdentifiers
        for id in availableLocaleIDs {
            let USA = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
            print(">>> '\(id)' \(USA.localizedString(forIdentifier: id) ?? "error, no translation available")")
        }

Answer (score 8):

I've a blog post with the right languages listed next to a screenshot of iOS 4's International settings to make it easier for you:
http://kb.applingua.com/2011/07/supported-ios-languages-which-languages/

Otherwise:

- English (U.S.)
- English (UK)
- French (France)
- German
- Traditional Chinese
- Simplified Chinese
- Dutch
- Italian
- Spanish
- Portuguese (Brazil)
- Portuguese (Portugal)
- Danish
- Swedish
- Finnish
- Norwegian
- Korean
- Japanese
- Russian
- Polish
- Turkish
- Ukrainian
- Hungarian
- Arabic
- Thai
- Czech
- Greek
- Hebrew
- Indonesian
- Malay
- Romanian
- Slovak
- Croatian
- Catalan
- Vietnamese

Comment: cool, thanks. it's been a while since I've asked the question and I came to the same conclusion as you in the meantime (figured out all the languages). thanks for confirming.

Comment: Now I am confused. How's that list any different from the list in the top link in my answer?

Comment: your links are as good. I just liked his answer a tiny bit better. that's all.

Comment: Don't know when this changed, but possible to do Region-Specific language translations like French Canadian now. In XCode, go to Project, Info, Localizations, press the + button, then scroll down to the bottom of the list of languages until you get to Other with right arrow, this will open a nice big list which includes regional variants for languages.

Comment: @FranciPenov links my become dead...

Comment: @Honey and lists can change... In this particular case both happened. The links are outdated, and the list in this answer has changed.

The difference is that links to official documentation have higher chance of being updated and kept correct until they disappear.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the list from Apple for all the available languages

```
static const char * const __CFBundleLanguageNamesArray[] = {
    "English",      "French",       "German",       "Italian",      "Dutch",        "Swedish",      "Spanish",      "Danish",
    "Portuguese",   "Norwegian",    "Hebrew",       "Japanese",     "Arabic",       "Finnish",      "Greek",        "Icelandic",
    "Maltese",      "Turkish",      "Croatian",     "Chinese",      "Urdu",         "Hindi",        "Thai",         "Korean",
    "Lithuanian",   "Polish",       "Hungarian",    "Estonian",     "Latvian",      "Sami",         "Faroese",      "Farsi",
    "Russian",      "Chinese",      "Dutch",        "Irish",        "Albanian",     "Romanian",     "Czech",        "Slovak",
    "Slovenian",    "Yiddish",      "Serbian",      "Macedonian",   "Bulgarian",    "Ukrainian",    "Byelorussian", "Uzbek",
    "Kazakh",       "Azerbaijani",  "Azerbaijani",  "Armenian",     "Georgian",     "Moldavian",    "Kirghiz",      "Tajiki",
    "Turkmen",      "Mongolian",    "Mongolian",    "Pashto",       "Kurdish",      "Kashmiri",     "Sindhi",       "Tibetan",
    "Nepali",       "Sanskrit",     "Marathi",      "Bengali",      "Assamese",     "Gujarati",     "Punjabi",      "Oriya",
    "Malayalam",    "Kannada",      "Tamil",        "Telugu",       "Sinhalese",    "Burmese",      "Khmer",        "Lao",
    "Vietnamese",   "Indonesian",   "Tagalog",      "Malay",        "Malay",        "Amharic",      "Tigrinya",     "Oromo",
    "Somali",       "Swahili",      "Kinyarwanda",  "Rundi",        "Nyanja",       "Malagasy",     "Esperanto",    "",
    "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",
    "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",
    "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",
    "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",             "",
    "Welsh",        "Basque",       "Catalan",      "Latin",        "Quechua",      "Guarani",      "Aymara",       "Tatar",
    "Uighur",       "Dzongkha",     "Javanese",     "Sundanese",    "Galician",     "Afrikaans",    "Breton",       "Inuktitut",
    "Scottish",     "Manx",         "Irish",        "Tongan",       "Greek",        "Greenlandic",  "Azerbaijani",  "Nynorsk"
};
```

// string, with groups of 3 characters being 1 element in the array of abbreviations

```
const char * __CFBundleLanguageAbbreviationsArray =
    "en\0"   "fr\0"   "de\0"   "it\0"   "nl\0"   "sv\0"   "es\0"   "da\0"
    "pt\0"   "nb\0"   "he\0"   "ja\0"   "ar\0"   "fi\0"   "el\0"   "is\0"
    "mt\0"   "tr\0"   "hr\0"   "zh\0"   "ur\0"   "hi\0"   "th\0"   "ko\0"
    "lt\0"   "pl\0"   "hu\0"   "et\0"   "lv\0"   "se\0"   "fo\0"   "fa\0"
    "ru\0"   "zh\0"   "nl\0"   "ga\0"   "sq\0"   "ro\0"   "cs\0"   "sk\0"
    "sl\0"   "yi\0"   "sr\0"   "mk\0"   "bg\0"   "uk\0"   "be\0"   "uz\0"
    "kk\0"   "az\0"   "az\0"   "hy\0"   "ka\0"   "mo\0"   "ky\0"   "tg\0"
    "tk\0"   "mn\0"   "mn\0"   "ps\0"   "ku\0"   "ks\0"   "sd\0"   "bo\0"
    "ne\0"   "sa\0"   "mr\0"   "bn\0"   "as\0"   "gu\0"   "pa\0"   "or\0"
    "ml\0"   "kn\0"   "ta\0"   "te\0"   "si\0"   "my\0"   "km\0"   "lo\0"
    "vi\0"   "id\0"   "tl\0"   "ms\0"   "ms\0"   "am\0"   "ti\0"   "om\0"
    "so\0"   "sw\0"   "rw\0"   "rn\0"   "\0\0\0" "mg\0"   "eo\0"   "\0\0\0"
    "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0"
    "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0"
    "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0"
    "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0" "\0\0\0"
    "cy\0"   "eu\0"   "ca\0"   "la\0"   "qu\0"   "gn\0"   "ay\0"   "tt\0"
    "ug\0"   "dz\0"   "jv\0"   "su\0"   "gl\0"   "af\0"   "br\0"   "iu\0"
    "gd\0"   "gv\0"   "ga\0"   "to\0"   "el\0"   "kl\0"   "az\0"   "nn\0";
```

Here is the link for reference 
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.13/CFBundle_Resources.c

Answer (score 2):

Locale list with all the countries and codes.

(Note(*) to get all the list run code on the device and not on simulator, which has limited languages only)

```
NSArray *allLocales = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
for (int i = 0; i < [allLocales count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode value:[allLocales objectAtIndex:i]],
          allLocales[i]);
}
```