# What are the locales supported by iOS 4 and 5?

Tags: ios, localization, locale

I would like to see the number and the listing or all locales (languages in this case) supported by iOS 4.x and the new version 5.0.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?  I am not exactly sure what good a list would do.

Comment: There are some answers for iOS 4 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328839/looking-for-a-list-of-all-available-languages-in-ios-4-x

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean, what good would a list do? This site doesn't work so when you approach questions in such a manner. Documentation describing the locales isn't instantly obvious when searching the internet and that should be reason enough.

Answer (score 0):

English (U.S.), English (UK), Chinese (Simplified), Chinese (Traditional), French, German, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Spanish, Arabic, Catalan, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, Finnish, Greek, Hebrew, Hungarian, Indonesian, Malay, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Portuguese (Brazil), Romanian, Russian, Slovak, Swedish, Thai, Turkish, Ukrainian and Vietnamese.

You can that list and a nice image of which languages are which on iOS here: http://kb.applingua.com/2011/07/which-languages-does-ios-support/