# App Store - Localization in how many languages

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization, app-store

I'm planning to release an international app so I want to provide localization for all the supported languages on the iPhone. Does there exist such a list?

And what would you think would be a bare minimum of languages supported?

Comment: possible duplicate of [looking for a list of all available languages in iOS 4.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328839/looking-for-a-list-of-all-available-languages-in-ios-4-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official list of supported iPhone languages is in Settings app > General > International > Language.

Comment: Take a screenshot and post it :)

Comment: It's a several pages long. Maybe I could get a screenshot from the iPad.

Comment: I normally use something like Autostitch panorama (not affiliated) to stick multiple screens together.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find this page useful:
http://www.small-apps.com/2012/02/which-language-where/?lang=en

It basically lists all languages supported by the App Store for localization of the app description. The problem is that most languages are not officially supported, so they all fall back to a default language (eg. both Norwegian and Polish show the UK English description).

I would say the bare minimum is English. The recommended minimum is EFIGS: English, French, Italian, German and Spanish. And if you want to reach everyone, you localize for all 18 languages supported by the App Store.