# How can I set my iOS device to have a locale of "en" instead of "en_US"?

Tags: ios7, locale, nslocale

According to this question here:

[Looking for a list of all available languages in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328839/looking-for-a-list-of-all-available-languages-in-ios)

There are numerous locales that have only a language code with no region code. Can anyone explain to me how to set my device into a state whereby the value of

```
[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]
```

is @"en" and not @"en_US"? I am trying to track down a bug and I believe it may be related to this state, which I cannot reproduce on my device or the simulator.

Note - I am aware that "en" is a language and not locale -- I am trying to reproduce a possible bug.

Comment: Have you looked at "Settings"?

Comment: I have; all settings force me to pick a country too

Answer (score 0):

Reading a different question/answer here on StackOverflow you can force the application to use a specific language:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", @"en", @"en_AU", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //to make the change immediate
```

Comment: I have tried this and sent him junk data or blank strings; no matter what the call to [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier] returns "en_US" (correctly I might add)